# Is there a smarter way to have all characters from A to Z in an enum (in a YAML file) without having to write all of them explicitly?

Tags: enums, yaml

I want to avoid the following:

```
query.skillLevel:
name: skillLevel
in: query
description: Skill level, A-Z.
type: string
enum:
 - A
 - B
 - C
 ....
 - Z
```

Is there any way I can just mention A..Z and it includes the characters in between?

Answer (score 0):

In plain YAML there is no way to do such a thing.

However if you can use tags and have control over the program loading the sequence you can e.g. do:

```
query.skillLevel:
name: skillLevel
in: query
description: Skill level, A-Z.
type: string
enum: !Range [A, Z]
```

and then have the object that gets created for the tag `!Range` behaves like a sequence that specifies all elements.

Although you have a key `enum` there is no enum in your YAML file. There are just mappings, lists and scalars.